# Cant launch Portal 2: Failed to load the launcher (libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gaming

I got a new computer downloaded [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com), and purchased [Portal](http://store.steampowered.com/app/400/), and downloaded it to both my old computer and my new computer. It launched instantly on my old computer, but, refused to launch on the new one. I tried launching the `portal2.sh` file from the terminal, and received:

> Failed to load the launcher (libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)

I used the terminal to locate `libuuid.so.1`, and received:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

I’ve been researching this issue for a while, and it looks like I need to create a symbolic link between `libuuid.so.1`, and `portal2.sh` using:

```
ln -s (path to libuuid.so.1) (path to portal2.sh)
```

However I am running Ubuntu, and cannot seem to find the file extension for `ibuuid.so.1.` According to Ubuntu, it is a `Link to shared library (application/x-sharedlib)` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the libraries your system has in place are in the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory, those would be 64 bit versions of the libraries. So if the application is complaining about not finding them—but you have similarly named libraries in that 64 bit directory—then it seems like your system needs the 32 bit versions of those libraries for [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com) to run.

This [thread on GitHub seems to address the issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/portal2/issues/167). Specifically [this post from “tazhate”](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/portal2/issues/167#issuecomment-37663275) which recommends running this `apt-get` command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs -y
```

Answer (score 2):

Today's Debian `testing` on `amd64` doesn't seem to have an `ia32-libs` package so I had to:

- install `libuuid1:i386`
- remove Portal 2's copy of `libstdc++.so.6` from `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Portal 2/bin`
- install `libfontconfig1:i386`
- install `libfreetype6:i386`
- install `libopenal1:i386`

Comment: Not sure about whether the packages are installed by default, but I don't see a copy of `libstdc++.so.6` anymore in any recent Source game (checked Portal 2, Portal Stories: Mel, CS:GO, HL2: Update, TF2 and Black Mesa).